# Copying WindowsImageBackup in command line

Tags: windows-7, backup, cmd.exe, windows-7-backup, windows-7-restore

I often restore Windows 7 system from a `WindowsImageBackup` folder from drive `d:` using a Windows installation disk. I also keep incremental backups on external HDD. Provided that I formatted `d:` how would I copy the Windows backup folder from an external drive ex. `g:\Something\W7Backup3` to `d:\WindowsImageBackup` using command line? I off course want to retain the folder structure, permissions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I copy the Windows backup folder from an external drive
>   using command line? I of course want to retain the folder structure,
>   permissions etc.

You can use the Windows native / built-in [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) command line tool with applicable syntax to perform this operation with a batch script. You can also run this with a copy and paste into a command prompt as well not in a batch script.

<sup>To run as a batch script though, save the logic to a *text document* on your desktop, etc. as `<something>.cmd` from the text document **file | save** options. Once saved, just double-click it to execute the logic, and confirm the files have been manipulated as expected afterwards.</sup>

```
SETLOCAL
SET SRC="g:\Something\W7Backup3"
SET ARCH="d:\WindowsImageBackup"
IF NOT EXIST "%ARCH%" MD "%ARCH%"
SET ARCHFName=*.*
SET LOG=G:\ImageBackupCopy.log
::   If you do not want a log file, remove the "/LOG+:%LOG%" below
SET OPT=/S /NP /R:5 /LOG+:%Log% /TS /FP
SET CMD=robocopy %SRC% %ARCH% %ARCHFName% %OPT%
%CMD%
```

Consider using the below [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) syntax where the `SET OPT=` options values are different than the above example if you have trouble with the security after the backup is complete.

```
SETLOCAL
SET SRC="g:\Something\W7Backup3"
SET ARCH="d:\WindowsImageBackup"
IF NOT EXIST "%ARCH%" MD "%ARCH%"
SET ARCHFName=*.*
SET LOG=G:\ImageBackupCopy.log
::   If you do not want a log file, remove the "/LOG+:%LOG%" below
SET OPT=/E /ZB /SEC /COPYALL /SECFIX /R:5 /W:5 /LOG+:%Log% /V
SET CMD=robocopy %SRC% %ARCH% %ARCHFName% %OPT%
%CMD%
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**Robocopy**](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: If I don't want the log can I also remove the `SET LOG=G:\ImageBackupCopy.log` line?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I didn't mention that but if it isn't removed when the `/LOG+:%LOG%` portion is removed, it wouldn't create it or cause any problems.... Sorry about that but you can remove that line as well.